# Commerce USPS not returning rates

Tags: 7, commerce

We are having trouble getting Commerce USPS configured properly to return rates. We are also unable to assign dimensions and weights to products, and are thinking that these are perhaps related.

We have a Product Type defined as "Product". We have Dimensions and Weight fields defined as follows:
Dimensions: field_product_dimensions /  Physical dimensions /   Dimensions textfields
Weight: field_product_weight /  Physical weight /   Weight textfield

When I edit a product, I can see the fields and enter data there, and save, but when I return to the product the fields are still blank.

I can assign default dimensions and weights to the Product Type, and when I edit a product, the defaults will appear. If I try to change the values and save, the defaults will appear again. I am hoping this is not a limitation, and that I can have unique values for dimensions and weights for products within a single Product Type.

Does anyone have any advice regarding saving individual product dimensions and weights?

At present, I can enter an order and checkout, but USPS shipping options are not being presented.

We have two shipping methods and services, Flat Rate and USPS. The Flat Rate charge (which we have set up as a handling charge to be applied to every order) shows up every time.

We have a rule set up for the USPS Shipping Method, with the condition "the order contains shippable products" and the action "Collect rates for a shipping method" (USPS).

Does anyone have any clues about how get USPS shipping options to appear?

Below are details on my server and module versions. All required dependent modules are installed and on. We have a live USPS account. We have tried to follow installation instructions in the ReadMe and any online documentation we can find.

Any ideas or tips are appreciated. Thanks!!

```
SERVER DETAILS
Drupal  7.38
Access to update.php    Protected
CTools CSS Cache    Exists
Colorbox plugin 1.5.14
Configuration file  Protected
Database system MySQL, MariaDB, or equivalent
Database system version 5.5.40-36.1-log
Database updates    Up to date
Date API    System date settings
The timezone has been set to America/New_York.
Drupal core update status   Up to date
PHP 5.3.29 (more information)
PHP extensions  Enabled
PHP memory limit    256M
PHP register globals    Disabled
Plupload library    1.5.8
Solr servers    1 server
Web server  Apache
Warning
XMP library is not available    SXMP library is not available
Functions SXMP are not available on the system. XMP metadata will not be extracted.
cURL    Enabled
```

```
Drupal core 7.38

MODULES
Address Field 7.x-1.1
Administration menu 7.x-3.0-rc5 Backup and Migrate 7.x-3.1
Better Exposed Filters 7.x-3.2
Chaos tool suite (ctools) 7.x-1.7
Colorbox 7.x-2.8 Update availablewarning
Recommended version:    7.x-2.9 (2015-Jun-21)   
Commerce Authorize.Net 7.x-1.2
Commerce Customizable Products 7.x-1.0-beta2
Commerce features 7.x-1.0
Commerce Flat Rate 7.x-1.0-beta2
Commerce PayPal 7.x-2.3
Commerce Physical Product 7.x-1.x-dev (2014-Oct-27)
Commerce Shipping 7.x-2.2
Commerce USPS 7.x-2.x-dev (2015-May-27)
Computed Field 7.x-1.0
Constant Contact 7.x-3.6
Context 7.x-3.6
Date 7.x-2.8 (Latest version:   7.x-2.9-rc1 (2015-Mar-27)   )
Devel 7.x-1.5
Diff 7.x-3.2
Drupal Commerce 7.x-1.11
Elements 7.x-1.4
Embed Views Display 7.x-1.2 (Also available:    7.x-2.0-beta2 (2012-Jun-22) )
Entity API 7.x-1.6
Entity Construction Kit (ECK) 7.x-2.0-rc7
Entity reference 7.x-1.1
Exif 7.x-1.2+5-dev (2013-Sep-30)  (Recommended version: 7.x-1.2 (2011-Nov-14)   )
Facebook Wall 7.x-1.8
Facet API 7.x-1.5
Facet API Bonus 7.x-1.1
Features 7.x-2.5 - Update availablewarning
Recommended version:    7.x-2.6 (2015-Jun-24)   
Field collection 7.x-1.0-beta8
Field Hidden 7.x-1.7
Field Slideshow 7.x-1.82 (Also available:   7.x-2.0-beta1 (2015-Mar-22) )
File entity (fieldable files) 7.x-2.0-beta1
File Entity Inline 7.x-1.0-beta1
File Lock 7.x-2.0
FileField Sources 7.x-1.9
FileField Sources Plupload 7.x-1.1
Google Analytics 7.x-2.1
jQuery Multi 7.x-1.0
jQuery Placeholder 7.x-1.0-beta2
Libraries API 7.x-2.2
Link 7.x-1.3
Link checker 7.x-1.2
Media 7.x-2.0-alpha4+37-dev (2015-Apr-24) : Update availablewarning
Recommended version:    7.x-2.0-alpha4 (2014-Oct-04)    
Development version:    7.x-2.x-dev (2015-Jun-30)   
Includes: Media, Media Bulk Upload, Media Field, Media Internet Sources, Media WYSIWYG, Media WYSIWYG View Mode
Media: YouTube 7.x-3.0
Menu Attach Block 7.x-1.20
Menu block 7.x-2.5 : Update availablewarning
Recommended version:    7.x-2.7 (2015-Jun-30)   
Metatag 7.x-1.4 : Update availablewarning
Recommended version:    7.x-1.6 (2015-Jun-30)   
Migrate 7.x-2.8
Module Filter 7.x-2.0
Multiple forms 7.x-1.1
Nodequeue 7.x-2.0-beta1 : Update availablewarning
Recommended version:    7.x-2.0 (2015-Jun-06)   
OAuth 7.x-3.2
Panels 7.x-3.5
Pathauto 7.x-1.2
Pathologic 7.x-2.12  (Also available:   7.x-3.0-beta2 (2014-Nov-08) )
Physical Fields 7.x-1.x-dev (2013-Oct-01)
Plupload integration 7.x-1.7
Redirect 403 to User Login 7.x-1.8
Rules 7.x-2.9
Search API 7.x-1.14 : Update availablewarning
Recommended version:    7.x-1.15 (2015-Jun-03)  
Search API pages 7.x-1.2
Search API Solr Search 7.x-1.5 : Update availablewarning
Recommended version:    7.x-1.8 (2015-Jun-15)   
Strongarm 7.x-2.0
Taxonomy Views Integrator 7.x-1.0-beta5
Token 7.x-1.6
Tweet Feed 7.x-1.12 (Also available:    7.x-3.0 (2015-Jun-14)   )
Views 7.x-3.11
Views Conditional 7.x-1.3
Views Field View 7.x-1.1
Webform 7.x-4.9
Wysiwyg 7.x-2.2+57-dev (2015-May-26) : Update availablewarning
Recommended version:    7.x-2.2 (2012-Oct-02)   
Development version:    7.x-2.x-dev (2015-Jun-29)
```

Comment: I'd try updating Commerce Physical to the latest -dev release as well Commerce USPS.